# Python 2.7 how to turn the string into a list outside the function with str.split()?

Tags: python-2.7, split

I wrote a function to turn a string y into a list
but after the function finishes, the string would stay as the original string.
what should I do to be able to process the object so that it's would become a list after the function ends?
I am new to programming so any sort of input would be greatly helpful, thank you very much.

```
def str_to_list(x):
    x = x.split(', ')
    print x 
    return 

y = "a, b, c, d, e"
str_to_list(y)
print y
```

Comment: I gave you tested, working solution :)

Comment: I just got a chance to work on it now, it's working fine so far, but I still got another question.  It seems like my only mistake is that I didn't return x.split(', ').  What's the meaning of returning x.split(', ') mean here?  returning x.split(', ') as the result of my function?   Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the array after splitting it

```
def str_to_list(x):
    return x.split(', ')

print str_to_list("a, b, c, d, e")
```

So yo can do

```
def str_to_list(x):
    return x.split(', ')

y = "a, b, c, d, e"
y = str_to_list(y)
print y
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise and effective answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def str_to_list(x):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        res.append(x[i])
    return res
```

Than call

```
y = str_to_list(y)
```

Comment: After testing out your method.  I finally understand what you did there.  Even though it's not what I was looking for.  It certainly is an interesting function.  Thanks for the input :)

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand what you meant

Comment: Yah, I didn't explain my question well I think.  Poor English sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You need to *return* your results, and re-assign the result back to `y`. You cannot replace the object `y` is bound to otherwise, and string object itself is otherwise immutable:

```
def str_to_list(x):
    x = x.split(', ')
    return x

y = "a, b, c, d, e"
y = str_to_list(y)
print y
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explaination.  I understand the reason to have return with an argument now.  Also what my mistake was.  Though the other guy's code is more concise.  Nonetheless, I appreciate for your explanation and time spent